# issue with Python Gtk+

Tags: python, linux, gtk

I can't nail exactly when/what update I did on my Lucid box but now I get:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gtk
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
>>>
```

Any hints?

UPDATED:

```
jldupont@server:~$ phidgets-manager 
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:15: GtkWarning: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.item_exit = gtk.MenuItem( "exit", True)
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:15: Warning: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.item_exit = gtk.MenuItem( "exit", True)
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:18: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  self.menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:18: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  self.menu = gtk.Menu()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_display: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: GtkWarning: gdk_x11_display_get_xdisplay: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/lib/phidgets-dbus/phidgetsdbus/apps/app_manager.py:50: GtkWarning: gdk_screen_get_number: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.tray=gtk.StatusIcon()
/usr/bin/phidgets-manager: line 10:  3899 Segmentation fault      python phidgets-manager.py
```

Comment: Have you tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before running?  And checked the thread @ http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-166863.html out?

Comment: @jdupont, I see exactly that, too, if I'm ssh'd in my lucid lynx box from another machine, but not if logged in _at_ the machines terminal on a graphic display.  How are you logged in?

Comment: @SB: thanks for the pointer: doesn't help.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: whether I am ssh'ing or physically at the machine, I get the error.  Also, I am not going through root for log in, just my normal account.

Comment: @jdupont: If you create a new user, and log in as the new user, does the same problem occur?

Comment: @~unutbu: just tried, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to get rid of the problem by completely reinstalling X:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg`

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`

Hope this helps someone!